# How do purchase contracts in DAPPs get to know when someone made a payment in fiat?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I have question about payment in fiat such as Credit Card. Recently I found some dapps(Sorare, nifty, etc.) adopted fiat payment methods into their P2P marketplaces.

1. How do their purchase contracts get to know when someone made a payment in fiat? Did they build some sort of Oracle? I am curious how they trigger their purchase contracts in this case though they seem they don't receive any signing from a buyer through wallet.
2. If the transaction is signed by dapp developer, how do contracts transfer NFTs to the buyer who is not the msg.sender?